# 403 Forbidden Access on XAMPP, plus weird bugs

Tags: apache, permissions, xampp, http-status-code-403, ubuntu-16.04

I have XAMPP installed on 2 computers (1 laptop and 1 desktop), both running Ubuntu 16.04.1. It was working perfectly fine on both until today, when it stopped working on my desktop. It still will connect to localhost and display all files and directories, like it should, **except** for my website folder. It just won't show up. If I try to access one of the website's files directly, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I tried giving my website files all permissions, and I still get the same error on my desktop but not on my laptop. The permissions are exactly the same, the files are exactly the same but it only works on my laptop. I tried copying the files that wouldn't work on my desktop to my laptop and they work there.

I also tried reinstalling XAMPP, to no effect. XAMPP has access to my website files on my laptop but not on my desktop.

Does anybody have an idea about what's causing this ? I find it really strange...

EDIT: I just found another problem, some files disappear for some reason when I transfer them from one computer to the other using my usb key.

EDIT 2: I just found a some kind of workaround, it's weird. I download my file from gdrive (where we keep our work). It comes as a zip archive. If I unzip the archive to any place on my desktop's ssd, it doesn't work (403 Error when I try to run it with XAMPP). However, if I unzip it to my USB key, it works...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the owner of the files is the same on both?
What about groups they belong to?
What's the user XAMPP is using to run?

Cheers,

Comment: The owner is the same on both (me), I don't know about the group though (I'm quite a newbie with linux to be honest). And XAMPP uses root to run.

Comment: I just read your edit 2. It looks like you're carrying over file permissions from one machine to the other one. Why don't you chown the files on the target computer to the right user and group?

You can check your user details by looking into /etc/passwd.

Also, I'd try chmod 777 on those files to confirm.